# codeigniter trigger background process

Tags: php, codeigniter, background-process

I am working on a module in PyroCMS which uses Codeigniter. In this module users submit some sort of order at front-end and the moderator of the site will be notified and checks the order at the back-end, then he updates the row and the user is notified about the change. All done right now.

I am going to make things a little automatic. The process of supplying the order which is an electronic good like document file, etc is to search the other server ( ftp ) for the order and bring it to the main server.

So, I propose this workflow:

- insert the row to the table ( front-end )
- initialize the robot to search the ftp server and set a flag that the
  robot is processing the order.
- if found: transfer the file to the server and update the row and
  flag.
- if not found update the flag and let the manager do the rest of the
  job.

Now, The thing is that I think it is not a good idea to put the robot code into the same controller and fire the robotic task with the http request from user. I mean, the form is submitted and I just want to insert the row and end the process and notify the user that it is submitted, then the robotic task should be done at the background.

Now we can update the workflow like:

- insert the new row
- notify the user that your order is submitted. and let user go.
- run the background process (trigger it) to search the ftp server and
  update the row upon success or do nothing upon error.

how can I do this type of background proccess? any idea or experience?

Comment: You can schedule a cronjob that will run each x minutes check if there's  anything to do, then do it, otherwise it will just exit.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your robot code to other php file and then run that php file using the php's system or exec command after successfull form submission. This will run like new php thread.
Hope this helps.